# How to make columns of a div table stretch across the full length?

Tags: html, css, alignment

Have the following problem. I need to make a table with columns that will stretch across the full length of a div block container, so it would look something like this:

[image]

However, what I have at the moment is something like this:

[image]

The code I use is:

```
  <div class="widgetright">
     <div class="widgettext">
     <b>This free independent travel guide to Russia</b> exists thanks to the commission we get when you order these <b>hand-picked trusted third-party services</b> or when you <b><a href="/book/">buy our book</a></b>. Please, support us!
     </div>
     &nbsp;<br>
     <div class="widgetable">
     <div class="widgetrow">
     <div class="widgetbars"><span class="centerer"></span><a href="/Travel/VisaSupport.html">russian visa</a></div><div class="gapper">           </div>
     <div class="widgetbars"><span class="centerer"></span><a href="/Services/TrainTickets.html">train tickets</a></div>
     </div>
     <div class="vertgapper"></div>
     <div class="widgetrow">
     <div class="widgetbars"><span class="centerer"></span><a href="/book/">guide book</a></div><div class="gapper"></div>
     <div class="widgetbars"><span class="centerer"></span><a href="/Services/Accommodation.html">hotels</a></div>
     </div>
     <div class="vertgapper"></div>
     <div class="vertgapper"></div>
     <div class="vertgapper"></div>
     <div class="vertgapper"></div>
     </div>
```

and the css is:

```
.widgetright {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
}
.widgettext {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.widgettext a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}

.widgettable {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 20px;

}

.widgetrow {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display:table-row;

}
.widgetbars {
    width: 40%;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    display:table-cell;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}

.widgetbars a {
    color: #333;
}

.widgetbars a:hover {
    color: #02aace;
    text-decoration: underline;

}

.centerer {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.gapper {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20px;
}
.vertgapper {
    display:table-row;

    height: 10px;

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Change the display of `widgetbars` to `inline-block`.

Comment: that's even worse. they just became all squares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add `display:table` to the `.widgetable`.

Since you're using table-row, using table on the parent element helps in mimicking a table structure.

After adding that, just do a quick spelling fix -- you have *widgettable* (with two T's) in the css, and a class named *widgetable* (with one T) on your actual element.

```css
.widgetright {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
}
.widgettext {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.widgettext a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}

.widgetable {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 20px;
    display:table;
}

.widgetrow {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display:table-row;

}
.widgetbars {
    width: 40%;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    display:table-cell;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}

.widgetbars a {
    color: #333;
}

.widgetbars a:hover {
    color: #02aace;
    text-decoration: underline;

}

.centerer {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.gapper {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20px;
}
.vertgapper {
    display:table-row;

    height: 10px;

}
```

```html
<div class="widgetright">
     <div class="widgettext">
     <b>This free independent travel guide to Russia</b> exists thanks to the commission we get when you order these <b>hand-picked trusted third-party services</b> or when you <b><a href="/book/">buy our book</a></b>. Please, support us!
     </div>
     &nbsp;<br>
     <div class="widgetable">
     <div class="widgetrow">
     <div class="widgetbars"><span class="centerer"></span><a href="/Travel/VisaSupport.html">russian visa</a></div><div class="gapper">           </div>
     <div class="widgetbars"><span class="centerer"></span><a href="/Services/TrainTickets.html">train tickets</a></div>
     </div>
     <div class="vertgapper"></div>
     <div class="widgetrow">
     <div class="widgetbars"><span class="centerer"></span><a href="/book/">guide book</a></div><div class="gapper"></div>
     <div class="widgetbars"><span class="centerer"></span><a href="/Services/Accommodation.html">hotels</a></div>
     </div>
     <div class="vertgapper"></div>
     <div class="vertgapper"></div>
     <div class="vertgapper"></div>
     <div class="vertgapper"></div>
     </div>
```

Comment: it's already there - `display:table` - but you were right: it was a typo in the style name. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
.widgetbars {
    width: 50%;
    margin-right:30px;
    ...
 }
```

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/4ry7agzp/

Comment: Yes, but it's a table div element, so it's not working with the current layout i have...

Comment: Is there a live version where I can check it out?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
    <div class="widgetright">
                 <div class="widgettext">
                 <b>This free independent travel guide to Russia</b> exists thanks to the commission we get when you order these <b>hand-picked trusted third-party services</b> or when you <b><a href="/book/">buy our book</a></b>. Please, support us!
                 </div>
                &nbsp;<br>


<div id="container">  /*New div added. Every thing is wraped inside it*/

             <div class="widgetable">
             <div class="widgetrow">
             <div class="widgetbars"><span class="centerer"></span><a href="/Travel/VisaSupport.html">russian visa</a></div><div class="gapper">           </div>
             <div class="widgetbars"><span class="centerer"></span><a href="/Services/TrainTickets.html">train tickets</a></div>
             </div>
             <div class="vertgapper"></div>
             <div class="widgetrow">
             <div class="widgetbars"><span class="centerer"></span><a href="/book/">guide book</a></div><div class="gapper"></div>
             <div class="widgetbars"><span class="centerer"></span><a href="/Services/Accommodation.html">hotels</a></div>
             </div>
             <div class="vertgapper"></div>
             <div class="vertgapper"></div>
             <div class="vertgapper"></div>
             <div class="vertgapper"></div>
             </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container
{
    display:flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
}

#container > * {
flex: 1 ;
}
```

Hope this helped.. And have a look at `flex` property of CSS3